# load page into div and keep the same page in div after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have loaded a page into div using jQuery. But when i refresh the webpage will go to initial stage?

How can i load the same page after refresh?

let the inital stage is

```
$("div").load("a.htm")
```

after clicking on a button it will load

```
$("div").load("b.htm")
```

now the division contains b.htm and after refreshing it is loading a.htm
I need to avoid this
if the div contains b.htm
after refreshing it should load the b.htm

how can i achive this????

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everytime you load a page into a div, you should alter the URL in the location bar to something like: `http://example.com/#b.html`. This will not navigate away from the current page, but when they reload (or open the saved bookmark), you can check the URL and use the part after `#` to indentify the page.

Comment: +1 imo the best approach as this also works when you go back and forth in the browser history.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to achieve this is to use [cookies](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/). Once you load `b.htm` with AJAX set a client cookie and when you refresh the page check for the presence of this cookie and load the appropriate page.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to keep a note of which page is currently loaded, store it somewhere (local browser storage, or perhaps server-side), and on reloading your page checking against it and re-loading the div's content.